# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when trying to read .xlsx excel file

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, file-upload, apache-poi

hello i try to read XLSX file with spring boot but i got error 
my controller :

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<?> addRfp  (@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException  {
    ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);  
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    String originalName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    String name = file.getName();
    String contentType = file.getContentType();
    long size = file.getSize();
    FileInputStream fis =  (FileInputStream) file.getInputStream();
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
    XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            switch (cell.getCellType())
            { case STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t"); break; 
                case NUMERIC: System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t"); break;
                case BOOLEAN: System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t"); break; 
                default : } } 
        System.out.println(""); }
return null;

}
```

the error is :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:43) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.readFrom(SharedStringsTable.java:123) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<init>(SharedStringsTable.java:111) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:684) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
```

please what  i should to do to resolve this i m already blocked now 
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks , AMINE

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? What version of `xmlbeans` are you using? Do they fit together according to https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components? Are you compiling the code using the same versions of `apache poi` and `xmlbeans` as are present while running?

Comment: 4.1.2 this is my version

Comment: Then `xmlbeans` must be version `3.1.0`. Is it? Are you compiling the code using the same versions of apache poi and xmlbeans as are present while running?

Comment: What prints following code:  `ClassLoader classloader = org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.class.getClassLoader();
  java.net.URL res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/poi/xssf/model/SharedStringsTable.class");
  String path = res.getPath();
  System.out.println("SharedStringsTable came from " + path);

  classloader = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.class.getClassLoader();
  res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.class");
  path = res.getPath();
  System.out.println("XmlOptions came from " + path);`

Comment: Thanks you very much so after executing  ur script i got this : SharedStringsTable came from file:/C:/Users/amine/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.2/poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar!/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/SharedStringsTable.class
XmlOptions came from file:/C:/Users/amine/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar!/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.class

Comment: So your `apache poi` version is `4.1.2` but your `xmlbeans` version is `2.3.0`. That does not fit. The `xmlbeans` version must be `3.1.0`.

Comment: what  i should to do idont found xml beans i my pom.xml

Comment: Sorry, can't help since I don't use Maven. But there must be `xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar` somewhere in your class path. But no clue why it is there. The `xmlbeans` version `3.1.0` is a prerequisite of `poi-ooxml-schemas` version `4.1.2` or `ooxml-schemas` version `1.4`. So Maven **should** choose that version. But, as often, Maven fails here, that's why I don't use it. Maybe you have any other library in your POM which has `xmlbeans` version `2.3.0` as a prerequisite?

Comment: thanks you very much  is workedd

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, try updating the project as it looks like the libraries are not loaded properly. Go to maven by right clicking on the project and maven update. Check the box forever update and it should work

Comment: after update i got already the same error :  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
so what i should to do please